# What does the error "unknown predicate `--output'" in my bash command refer to?

Tags: bash, sh, travis-ci

I'm using the following command, on my Mac, this works fine, but on Ubuntu, this results in the error mentioned below.

Any suggestions why this happens?

```
find './_build' \
    -type 'f' \
    -name '*.js' \
    -exec echo "{}" \; \
    -exec uglifyjs --output "{}" "{}" \;
```

The output is:

```
find: unknown predicate `--output'
```

Comment: It's probably related to your quoting the `{}` (you should not do it, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647). If you correct it, as I verified, the problem should be solved, but I have no idea why.

Comment: What version of find do you have `find --version` ? maybe you can try to replace `-exec echo ...` with `-print`

Comment: @Quasímodo hmm, removing the quotes doesn't seem to help :-(

Comment: @Philippe can't see because it is Travis-CI...

Comment: Can you replace first `-exec` ?

Comment: Did it, but still the same result :-( now I have `find './_build' \
    -type 'f' \
    -name '*.js' \
    -exec uglifyjs --output {} {} \;`